# associatedtype protocol conformance issues

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 protocols to define a relationship where a `Mediator` uses `Host` to extract `Client`

1. `Host`
2. `Client`
3. `Mediator`

My goal is to have `Host` also act as a `Mediator`. These are my class and protocol definitions:

```
class Host {}
class Client {}

protocol HostProtocol {}
protocol ClientProtocol {}

extension Host: HostProtocol {}
extension Client: ClientProtocol {}

protocol MediatorProtocol {
    associatedtype H = HostProtocol
    associatedtype C = ClientProtocol

    func getClientFrom(host: H) -> C?
}
```

I then extend my `MediatorProtocol` to add an implementation

```
extension MediatorProtocol where H == Host, C == Client {
    func getClientFrom(host: H) -> C? {
        return Client()
    }
}
```

Now when I try to make my Host conform to MediatorProtocol, I get an error saying

> Type 'Host' does not conform to protocol MediatorProtocol

```
extension Host: MediatorProtocol {}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change protocol specification on this

```
extension MediatorProtocol where H == Host, C == Client {
    func getClientFrom(host: Host) -> Client? {
        return Client()
    }
}
```

You can rewrite it even without `where` spec. Swift can infer associated types from function declaration (that's why it couldn't do so with your code).

```
extension MediatorProtocol {
    func getClientFrom(host: Host) -> Client? {
        return Client()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why changing the params to their concrete implementation in the protocol extension removed the error?

Comment: I'm not a compiler expert but as far as I understand H and C are aliases meaning its do not contain any type information. In order to substitute (infer type of) aliases correctly you need to specify concrete types in implementation. But you did try to use aliases instead of types. `where` clause doesn't substitute aliases on types it just put a constraint on specialized declaration. In this case it doesn't actually do something because we constrain implementation with concrete types.